# ASP.NET Dynamic Data DisplayColumn Attribute Causing Sorting Issue

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

Using ASP.NET Dynamic Data with a LINQ to SQL DataContext from the Northwind Database...

When I add a DisplayColumn Attribute to one of my LINQ to SQL `entity` classes and reference a property from my custom code in the partial class, I lose the ability to sort by that column in the generated *GridViews*.  I continue to lose the ability to sort even if I reference a non-custom property as the `sortColumn`.

Why is this happening?

Example Code:

```
[DisplayColumn("LastNameFirstName", "LastName", false)]
public partial class Employee
{
    public string LastNameFirstName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }
}
```

Aaron

EDIT:  The `sortColumn` specifies the column that will be used to sort this entity when it is used as a foreign key (in a *DropDownList*), not when it is being sorted in the *GridView*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be by Design...

The "sortColumn" specifies the column that will be used to sort this entity when it is used as a foreign key (in a DropDownList), not when it is being sorted in the GridView.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct because the property is not in the DB and linq to SQL will try to construct a T-SQL quert to the DB to get your entities. but will fail because these is no column with that name.

Comment: But the second parameter, "LastName", would be in the DB.  And if I specify it there, I think it should be trying to sort by that.  Either way it could sort by the custom property after it creates the Domain Objects...

Comment: Yes but the filed LastNameFirstName is not in the DB and Linq does not know about what goes on inside LastNameFirstName :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the ToString() method that might work but it would only filter on the entity referenced by the FK relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **[ScaffoldColumn(true)]** - it might trick dynamic data to enable sorting

```
[DisplayColumn("LastNameFirstName", "LastName", false)]
public partial class Employee
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public string LastNameFirstName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }
}
```