# Sorting by multiple fields using DisplayColumnAttribute in Asp.Net Dynamic Data App?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I've got a dynamic data app, and I want to sort based on multiple fields like so..

```
<DisplayColumn("FieldName", "Field1, Field2")> _
```

DisplayColumn doesn't seem to support more than one field?

Answer (score 2):

The DisplayColumn attribute's SortColumn param specifies the column that will be used to sort this entity when it is used as a foreign key (ex: in a DropDownList), not when it is being sorted in the GridView (or being sorted in the DB).

see SO here as well:
[ASP.NET Dynamic Data DisplayColumn Attribute Causing Sorting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731502/asp-net-dynamic-data-displaycolumn-attribute-causing-sorting-issue)

msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displaycolumnattribute.aspx

If this is still what you are looking for (sorting in DropDownLists only, not the DB) you can sort on multiple columns by creating a custom property in the entity that combines those two columns.

example:

```
[DisplayColumn("FieldName", "SortColumn")]
public partial class Employee
{
    public string SortColumn
    {
        get { return Field1 + Field2; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort gridview on multiple columns then this is how you can do -

In Page Template\List.aspx.cs & in Page_Laod event check for table name

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
    if (table.Name == "Project")
{

GridView1.Sort("ClientDetail.CompanyName asc,ProjectName asc", SortDirection.Ascending);

```
}
```

}

and you can also provide order either ascending or descending for each column.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does support multiple field. You can try this:

```
[DisplayColumn("FieldName", "Field1 ASC, Field2 DESC, Field3")]
```

Then in `Page_Load` of `List.aspx`:

```
var displayColumn = table.GetAttribute<DisplayColumnAttribute>();
if (displayColumn != null && displayColumn.SortColumn != null)
{
    GridView1.Sort(displayColumn.SortColumn,
    displayColumn.SortDescending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

Comment: Sure, this will work if you manually sort, but it pretty much messes up Dynamic Data in general and causes yellow screens for any attempted automatic sorts, so it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Aaronaught, what will be a better way?

Comment: Aaron's answer works if performance isn't a concern. Otherwise I'd use a computed column which can be indexed on the server. It would be nice if DD just plonked whatever string you choose into an `ORDER BY` but unfortunately that's not what it does, and making this work ultimately ends up being more hassle than just working within the framework by synthesizing a single column.